# Make window scale to screen size in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm currently developing a web browser in Python using Qt5. Just wondering: How can I make the window scale to the screen size? For example, Chromium and Firefox adapt to the size of the screen they're on when maximized.

Here's how Chromium displays Google when maximized:

[image]

**EDIT:** Since I was requested to add some example code, here is the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget 
from ui_output import Ui_Form

app = QApplication(sys.argv) 


class MainWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form):   
    def __init__(self, parent=None):     
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)     
        self.setupUi(self)     
        self.go_button.clicked.connect(self.pressed)   
    def pressed(self):     
        self.webView.setUrl(QUrl(self.lineEdit.displayText()))

view = MainWindow() 
view.show() 
view.showMaximized()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: execute: `your_window.showMaximized()`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks, it now runs maximised, but how do I scale WebView to the size of my window?

Comment: What do you mean by Webview, you mean QWebEngineView or QWebView, you could provide a [mcve] to understand you better because your explanation does not understand it, you could also show an image of your problem.

Comment: I've added some code.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kz8roq

Comment: I see where the problem is, share your .ui file to help you

Comment: Can you share the .ui file?

Answer (score 6):

You have to learn to use the layouts, these elements are used to manage the sizes of the widgets within another.

In Qt Designer the task is very simple, in your case select the 4 elements at the top and press the button: [image] and then press in an empty space inside the main window and press the button: [image]. At the end you will get the following structure:

[image]

[image]

Generating the following .ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
       <property name="text">
        <string>&lt;---</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>---&gt;</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="go_button">
       <property name="text">
        <string>GO</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QWebView" name="webView">
     <property name="url">
      <url>
       <string>about:blank</string>
      </url>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QWebView</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**ui_output.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ui_output.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.go_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.go_button.setObjectName("go_button")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.go_button)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.webView = QtWebKitWidgets.QWebView(Form)
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("about:blank"))
        self.webView.setObjectName("webView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.webView)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "<---"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "--->"))
        self.go_button.setText(_translate("Form", "GO"))

from PyQt5 import QtWebKitWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore ,QtWidgets
from ui_output import Ui_Form


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):   
    def __init__(self, parent=None):     
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)     
        self.setupUi(self)     
        self.go_button.clicked.connect(self.pressed)   
    def pressed(self):     
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(self.lineEdit.displayText()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    view = MainWindow() 
    view.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]